# How to use argument in a string in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to give the path to a file as an argument for a script and that same argument, I am using to get the location of the particular file.

```
myvar1= $(basename ${1}/mydir/file*)

echo "File Name is ${myvar1}"
```

And trying to execute the script as

```
bash new.sh /home/usr/test
```

My file is actually as /home/usr/test/mydir/file2039.

The execution is giving an error with:

```
new.sh: line 1: file2039: command not found
File Name is
```

Can anyone suggest what is going wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: You have a typo: You have a space after the equal sign, and therefore `myvar1` stays empty.

Comment: no spaces around `=`